# How can I set the AnchorShadowVariable before triggering afterVariableChanged?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm working on an Optaplanner solution using the TWVRP example as a basis, I however need to grab some info from the chain anchor in order to correctly calculate arrival time (specifically, the anchor holds info whether this chain is served by car, bike or by foot).
When attaching a debugger, I can see that the methods are called in the following order:

```
beforeVariableChanged
setPlanningVariable
afterVariableChanged
setAnchorShadowVariable
```

This means that when in `afterVariableChanged`, I have to recurse down through the chain of planning entities until i hit the anchor to get the currently valid anchor. Is there any way to have `setAnchorShadowVariable` called before `afterVariableChanged` so that I just can `getAnchorShadowVariable` in `afterVariableChanged` in my variable listener?

Answer (score 0):

There is, **using the `sources` attribute.**

In the example below, presume A is your genuine variable,
C is your anchor shadow variable and D is your custom shadow variable.

Because D (your customer shadow variable) is sourced on C (the anchor variable) (and maybe A too), *by the time ANY afterVar for a C variable on ANY instance triggers, ALL the afterVars for the A and B variables on ALL instances have already triggered*, so the model is reliable.

[image]

(This applies even if the move changes multiple genuine variables etc: the shadow variables afterVar methods are triggered at the end of the move.)

Note: beforeVar methods do not behave this way, they trigger immediately, because delaying them would make them useful to capture information before the data changes.

Since OptaPlanner 6.4 or something. Before that version, the trigger order was naturally arbitrary (= non delayed), which could make users go insane.

Comment: OK, so you are correct in that today, my custom shadow variable (D) has as its source my genuine variable (A). By instead making D use C as its source, my listener will trigger after the anchor change? Basically changing @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = ArrivalTimeListener.class, sources = {@PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "genuineVariableName")})
    to @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = ArrivalTimeListener.class, sources = {@PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "anchorVariableName")})

Comment: Exactly, try that.